# "cache" cvWarpPerspective map

Tags: opencv

I'm using the same matrix in cvWarpPerspective for several frames. Now I noticed that a lot of time seems to be spent creating maps for cvRemap. I would love to

- cache the Maps that are created for cvRemap
- maybe even combine that map with an undistortion map

I can't figure out how to create the maps from my 3x3 matrix myself quickly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no OpenCV function to create the maps for you, but I did the same by copying the code from warpPerspective (the map creation part)

It's easy because warpPerspective creates the maps, then calls remap() with them.

In order to optimize memory usage, warpPerspective calculates the maps for small blocks - you have to modify it to create the full map.

As for combining it with distortion, you have to write your custom map generator - you'll need some math there.